# Função recursiva JS

Tags: javascript, funções, recursão, condição

estou estudando um pouco de função recursiva e me deparei com um exercicio que ta tirando o meu sono, por ser um exercicio básico e nao estou entendendo a saida.
Basicamente o livro pede para criar uma função para testar se um número é PAR ou nao, retornando um valor boleano. Mas a função teria que cumprir os seguintes requisitos.

```
se o valor passado for 0 return true
se o valor passado for 1 return false
para qualquer outro valor faça n - 2 ate reduzi-lo a 0 ou 1.
```

a minha função ficou assim:

```
function epar(x){
    if(x==0){
        return true
    }
    else if(x==1){
        return false
    }
    else{
        epar(x-2)
    }
}
console.log(epar('parametro'))
```

O que não entendendo é que quando eu coloco algum valor diferente de 1 ou 0, ele retorna um valor undefined. Eu fiz alguns testes por exemplo fazendo imprimir o valor passado cada vez que retornasse a função e realmente o valor vai diminuindo como eu gostaria, mas por algum motivo ele tao ta retornando nem true nem false.

Comment: tens de dar `return` nesse `epar(x-2)`, senão a função não retorna nada nesse ciclo recursivo.

Comment: Vc precisa retornar o valor, dentro do `else` deve ser  `return epar(x-2)`. E como essa função só trabalha com números, não faz sentido chamar passando uma string, então deveria ser algo como `console.log(epar(5))` (passo 5 ou qualquer outro número, pois não faz sentido passar o texto `'parametro'` se ela só trabalha com números)

Comment: entendo, muito obrigado, esse valor ai ta uma string so pra exemplificar que estaria passando um parametro qualquer, eu tava passando numeros, irei testar com o return mt obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Tens de dar `return` nesse `epar(x-2)`, senão a função não retorna nada e esse ciclo recursivo não passa o resultado para fora.

```js
function epar(x) {
  if (x == 0) {
    return true
  } else if (x == 1) {
    return false
  } else {
    return epar(x - 2)
  }
}
console.log(epar(24));
console.log(epar(23));
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, não sabia disso não!!